# How do I add +symbol to the varchar in Sql database

Tags: mysql

```
Declare @mobile varchar(20)
If @mobile like '971%'
Begin
Set @mobile='+'+@mobile
End
```

If I pass mobile number as `9715628`...

I should get the result as `+9715628...`

Comment: Hi Krishna508 and welcome to Stack Overflow. It looks like you have some code written already - can you describe whether that is working or not, and what specific issue you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Use `CONCAT`.

```
Set @mobile=CONCAT('+', @mobile);
```

`+` in MySQL denotes arithmetic addition operation.

You cannot use `+` to concatenate strings in MySQL.